# Select in LINQ with a strange value @p__linq__0

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I have this select in LINQ

```
 public List<EquipamentoNoDiscovery> GetEquipamentosNoDiscovery(int imID)

var lista = (from ma in ctx.macaddress
                         join m in ctx.mac on
                       ma.address_mac equals m.mac_id into g1
                         from m in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()

                         join ml in ctx.mac_link on
                         m.mac_id equals ml.mac_id into g2
                         from ml in g2.DefaultIfEmpty()

                         join im in ctx.immobile on
                         ml.link_id equals im.immobile_id into g3
                         from im in g3.DefaultIfEmpty()

                         join en in ctx.enterprise on
                          im.enterprise_id equals en.enterprise_id into g4
                         from en in g4.DefaultIfEmpty()

                         join pl in ctx.port_link on
                        ma.address_id equals pl.address_id into g5
                         from pl in g5.DefaultIfEmpty()

                         join p in ctx.port on
                         new { pl.sw_id, pl.port_id } equals new { p.sw_id, p.port_id }

                         join s in ctx.switch_lan on
                        pl.sw_id equals s.sw_id into g6
                         from s in g6.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where pl.address_id == imID
                         select new
                         {
                             Regiao = en.enterprise_u_name,
                             Predio = im.immobile_u_name,
                             Equipamento = m.host,
                             TipoPlaca = m.mac_type,
                             Mac = ma.address_mac,
                             Ip_ma = ma.address_ip,
                             Ip_m = m.ip_address,
                             Comunidade = s.sw_community,
                             IpSwitch = s.sw_ip,
                             PortaIndex = p.port_index,
                             PortaNome = p.port_name
                         });

            ObjectQuery oQuery = (ObjectQuery)lista;
            string cmdSQL = oQuery.ToTraceString();
```

When I use the command  oQuery.ToTraceString(), I can see this  "where pl.address_id == imID" become this  "WHERE [Extent6].[address_id] =  @p_*linq*_0".
Then my select always return empty, if in SQL command I change the value  @p_*linq*_0 to a number, It works fine.
Any suggestions, please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's just a query parameter which comes from this `where` claused.

```
where pl.address_id == imID
```

Your log should also show the value which has been passed for that parameter, which should be the value of `imID`. Check that value - it's possible that it's not what you expected it to be.

Comment: in debugging mode I can see imID has the value  2 like it was expected but it doesnt work any way. Only in SQL command

Comment: @Sah: What's the type of `address_in` in your database?

Comment: It is PK, FK, int, not null

Comment: @Sah: Then it really *should* work fine. A query using a parameter with a value of 2 should work the same way as putting 2 directly into the query, I'd expect...

Comment: I changed this "where im.enterprise_id == imID" to this "im.enterprise_id == 2". But it still is not working. =/

Comment: @Sah: I would start off with a *much* smaller query, and build up from there, so you can see where it goes wrong.

Comment: I'm going do that, if i find the trouble, I post here.  Thanks a lot

Comment: After I tried update model from database from edmx option, it worked fine. I'm not sure about the cause of it but I imagine something about relationship  on the database. Problem solved. Thanks!